# Passing lat/long values not working in Google Maps Directions API

Tags: javascript, php, html

From the documentation, it should be possible to use lat,long values  for origin as well as destination to get the route in google maps directions api. For some reasons I am getting an error doing this. The code is shown below. It works alright if i use the addresses. In the code, if the var pkup is in lat,long value, the var dest is in address format, I get a totally different route. However, if both var pkup and var dest are in address format, the route plots ok. What could i be doing wrong? The code is an example from the documentation. Please help, thanks.

```
    <html>
  <head>
    <title>Routes</title>
    <script src="https://polyfill.io/v3/polyfill.min.js?features=default"></script>

    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="./style.css" />
    <script type="module" src="./index.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
<div id="map" style="height:50%; width:75%;"></div>
    <script src=" https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=APIKEY"></script>
    <script src="app.js"></script>

    <div class="pac-card" id="pac-card">
      <div>
        <div id="title"><b></b></div>
        <div style="display: none;" id="type-selector" class="pac-controls">
          <input
            type="radio"
            name="type"
            id="changetype-all"
            checked="checked"
          />
          <label for="changetype-all">All</label>

          
        </div>
        <br />
        <div style="display: none;" id="strict-bounds-selector" class="pac-controls">
          <input type="checkbox" id="use-location-bias" value="" checked />
          <label for="use-location-bias">Bias to map viewport</label>

          <input type="checkbox" id="use-strict-bounds" value="" />
          <label for="use-strict-bounds">Strict bounds</label>
        </div>
      </div>
<p id="pkup"><?php echo $_POST['pkup']; ?></p>
<p id="dest"><?php echo $_POST['destination']; ?></p>
<p id="total"></p>

</b>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div id="map"></div>
    <div id="infowindow-content"      <span id="place-name" class="title"></span><br />
      <span id="place-address"></span>
    </div>

<script type="text/javascript">

function initMap() {


  const map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map"), {
    zoom: 4,
    center: { lat: 7.3782, lng: 3.9062 }, // Osogbo Nigeria.
  });
  const directionsService = new google.maps.DirectionsService();
  const directionsRenderer = new google.maps.DirectionsRenderer({
    draggable: true,
    map,
    panel: document.getElementById("panel"),
  });


  directionsRenderer.addListener("directions_changed", () => {
    const directions = directionsRenderer.getDirections();

    if (directions) {
      computeTotalDistance(directions);
    }
  });
var pkup=document.getElementById("pkup").innerHTML;
var dest=document.getElementById("dest").innerHTML;

  displayRoute(
    "Osogbo, Nigeria",
    dest,
    directionsService,
    directionsRenderer
  );
}

function displayRoute(origin, destination, service, display) {
  service
    .route({
      origin: origin,
      destination: destination,
      
      travelMode: google.maps.TravelMode.DRIVING,
      avoidTolls: true,
    })
    .then((result) => {
      display.setDirections(result);
    })
    .catch((e) => {
      alert("Could not display directions due to: " + e);
    });
}

function computeTotalDistance(result) {
  let total = 0;
  const myroute = result.routes[0];

  if (!myroute) {
    return;
  }

  for (let i = 0; i < myroute.legs.length; i++) {
    total += myroute.legs[i].distance.value;
  }

  total = total / 1000;
  document.getElementById("total").innerHTML = total + " km";
}

window.initMap = initMap;


</script>

   <!-- 
      The `defer` attribute causes the callback to execute after the full HTML
      document has been parsed. For non-blocking uses, avoiding race conditions,
      and consistent behavior across browsers, consider loading using Promises.
      See https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/load-maps-js-api
      for more information.
      -->
    <script
      src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=APIKEY&callback=initMap&libraries=places&v=weekly"
      defer
    ></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Is this a JS problem, or a PHP problem? What have you tried to resolve it?

Comment: @Nico Haase - I believe it is a JS question. I have tried using addresses for both origin and destination and it worked. I have posted my issue to see if anyone has a similar experience and how it was resolved. A working code will also be appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: Please add all clarification to your question by editing it. If this is not a PHP problem, please share the generated markup (without any PHP code)